# What is 'Getty'? I noticed there are six occurences of it in my System Monitor

Tags: 11.10, laptop, system-monitor

I'm just curious what 'Getty' is and what it does. The past few days I have noticed that there are always at least six instances of it in System Monitor, each using about 640 KiB memory and status says "n_tty_read".

What does this mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`getty` is what sits on the text-mode consoles and waits for someone to log in.  It configures the tty device and spawns `login` when typed at; historically it adapted to the communications line based on what it received, but especially on VCs this is no longer necessary.

Comment: Ok, I just don't understand why I would have 6 going all the time. Is this anything to be concerned about or is this something that is harmless?

Comment: This is nothing to be concerned about. It is common to have six virtual terminals each of which will have getty running unless you are logged in.

Comment: Is it okay to remove `getty` from server? I just need assurance that it won't affect logins of users.